# Mathematica: strange behavior of Part when applied to a List replaced with Rule

Tags: list, replace, wolfram-mathematica, rule

Could anyone please explain, why

```
a[[1]] /. {a -> {{1}, {2}}}
```

returns the error `Part::partd: Part specification a[[1]] is longer than depth of object.`

and also

```
(Transpose[a])[[1]] /. {a -> {{1}, {2}}}
```

returns

```
{{1}, {2}}
```

while

```
(Transpose[{{1}, {2}}])[[1]]
```

returns

```
{1, 2}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this expression

```
a[[1]] /. {a -> {{1}, {2}}}
```

the sub-expression to the left of `/.` will be evaluated first and, if `a` doesn't have a first part, *Mathematica* will complain.

For your second expression

```
(Transpose[a])[[1]]
```

try evaluating `FullForm[(Transpose[a])]`. This should return an expression (no *Mathematica* on this machine, so I'm not 100% sure but I suspect it will return `Transpose[a]`, ie the original expression is not evaluated because *Mathematica* has no rule to transform it to anything else.)

`Part`, when applied to expressions, applies to their `FullForm` and the `Part[FullForm[(Transpose[a])],1]` is `a`, which is then available for the replacement rule to operate on.

Again, evaluate `FullForm[(Transpose[{{1}, {2}}])]`, you should be starting to get the picture by now.

I've now checked this on my *Mathematica* machine, my guesses at what is going on are OK.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I didn't realize the rules apply to the expression on the left after it is evaluated.

Comment: Have a look at `Hold` and its relations, and the documentation on *Mathematica*'s evaluation process.  There are ways to interfere with how expressions are evaluated, though none of them are for the faint-hearted.